# Why doesn't this code for collision work in unity Mobile 2D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This code is attached to my player by a script named `PlayerCollision`**:**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerCollision : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    void Update()
    {
        
    }

    void OnCollisionEnter (Collision collision)
    {
        if (collision.collider.tag == "Finish")
        {
            Debug.Log("Level Finished");
        }
    }
}
```

Can Someone tell me why this code is not displaying `Level Finished` in the Console

Comment: What is the value of  collision.collider.tag? Can you debug please

Comment: The collision.collider.tag value is Finish

Comment: I don’t know unity, but is there Console.WriteLine which can help you?

Comment: @Nikolathedev Make sure there is a collider on the Player gameobject and the gameobject the player is colliding with.

(Also @viveknuna `Debug.Log` is the equivalant of `Console.writeLine` in Unity)

Comment: There is a collider on the player

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's a 2D game, I think you want to use `OnCollisionEnter2D`: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnCollisionEnter2D.html

```cs
    void OnCollisionEnter2D (Collision2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.collider.tag == "Finish")
        {
            Debug.Log("Level Finished");
        }
    }
```

Comment: **thelukaszns** It works now!

Comment: @Nikolathedev Glad it works! Make sure to accept the answers that helped you:)

Comment: **thelukaszns** I accepted your answer. It didn't Allow me to accept it  at first, it said I needed to wait 7 more minutes before I could accept an answer.